# Relationship between holding time and sharpe ratio

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, sharpe-ratio, longshort

Let's say, for simplicity, I have a long-only portfolio $P$ that consists solely of equity.

The average holding period for each asset is $n$ days. Are there research papers or theorems that investigate the relationship between the Sharpe ratio $S$ of the portfolio and the holding period $n$?

Intuitively, I would argue that the larger $n$ is, the higher the likelihood of the portfolio performing in line with the market. Thus, a larger $n$ might result in a lower Sharpe ratio. For instance, how challenging would it be to construct a long-only portfolio with $n = 90$ that has a Sharpe ratio of $1.5$?

Comment: Welcome to Quant.Stackexchange!